# for /f command doesn't work properly (for me)

Tags: command-line

I have a problem with something. I'm a beginner and a noob in batch so sorry if this is a stupid question. I made a text file like this:

```
User/Jack

Password/Pancake

Status/Hello
```

I wanted to show the password only so I used the for /f command. ;

```
for /f "delims=/ skip=1 tokens=2" %%a in (Users.txt) do (
    set Password=%%a 
)
```

When I tried that, "Hello" popped up in my cmd window. I've been trying to fix this for hours but I haven't found a solution yet. Could you guys help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

On each turn through loop (iteration) you're assigning the text token to "Password", overwriting whatever it contained previously.  So after the For loop finishes, "Password" will contain `Hello` as it's the last thing you assign to "Password".

I'm assuming you have `echo password` or alike after the loop to display it; if so, move that into the loop so that is displays the variable on each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are close to the solution, but you are skipping the first line, then processing each of the remaining lines, so the resultant value is always from the *last* line.

One solution that occurs to me is:-

```
for /f "delims=/ tokens=1*" %%a in (Users.txt) do (
    if "%%a" == "Password" set Password=%%b 
)
```

This reads each line and splits it into `%%a`, the text before the `/`, and `%%b`, the rest of the line after the `/`. The `Password` variable is set only when the first field matches.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really helped me out! Thanks man :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways this can be fixed, but the easiest in your case would be to re-order the "users.txt" and put the last line as "Password/Pancake" and set your "skip" value to 2. This will fix your issue.

I reccomend though to redo the script in a more generic manner so that you can actually fetch something that you don't know the position of.

Comment: I'm sorry to say this, but from a programmers point of view, it is never a good suggestion to alter the input in such way that your script starts working. I won't vote down your answer, because technically you are correct, but it is bad practice and not recommended to do so.

Comment: @LPChip: I agree, but this does fix the issue. That's why I recommended at the bottom to redo the script in a generic manner. I just didn't have time to redo the whole script myself.